# ActionButton from Getting Started tutorial does not work

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm absolutely new to firefox add-on development and I can't understand why does the simplest example from the tutorial not work.

I accurately followed all the steps from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started
and I can't find the add-on button anywhere in the browser window. Standard buttons only:
[image]

add-on sdk seems to be set up properly, cfx works fine. Here is the console output of `cfx run`:

```
(addon-sdk-1.17)[12:40:05]sergey@linuxmain:my-addon> cfx run
Using binary at '/usr/bin/firefox'.

(process:10986): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Using profile at '/tmp/tmpPxd9iD.mozrunner'.

(process:10996): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(process:11006): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
[10996] WARNING: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised: 'glib warning', file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp, line 140

(firefox:10996): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
[10996] WARNING: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised: 'glib warning', file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp, line 140

(firefox:10996): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
[10996] WARNING: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised: 'glib warning', file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp, line 140

(firefox:10996): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
[10996] WARNING: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised: 'glib warning', file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp, line 140

(firefox:10996): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
JavaScript error: resource://app/components/nsBrowserGlue.js, line 1610: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIPrefBranch.getComplexValue]
```

What the last line of this output is about? Maybe it is the reason?

Add-on files and Python version:

```
(addon-sdk-1.17)[12:46:06]sergey@linuxmain:my-addon> ls data/
icon-16.png  icon-32.png  icon-64.png
(addon-sdk-1.17)[12:46:10]sergey@linuxmain:my-addon> cat lib/main.js
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("https://www.mozilla.org/");
}
(addon-sdk-1.17)[12:46:15]sergey@linuxmain:my-addon> python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

I run Firefox version 36.0. The add-on itself is present:
[image]

So what am I missing? How to bring add-on button to the panel?

**Upd:**

If I disable the addon, open & clear browser console and then re-enable addon, then I get the following console output:

```
Warning: attempting to write 4867 bytes to preference extensions.bootstrappedAddons. This is bad for general performance and memory usage. Such an amount of data should rather be written to an external file.
Warning: attempting to write 4670 bytes to preference extensions.xpiState. This is bad for general performance and memory usage. Such an amount of data should rather be written to an external file.
```

So there are no red-colored errors.

Comment: You might have an addon startup error. To check this easily first disable the addon, then open the browser console, click on 'clear' to clear all the messages, then enable the addon again. You should see any errors or exceptions related specifically to your addon's initialization.

Comment: Also, your code works fine for me using cfx or [jpm](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm) tested in Firefox 36 as well as a current nightly build. What version are you running?

Comment: @canuckistani I run version 36.0. I tried to disable and re-enable addon as you said (added results to the question), but it didn't show any errors. Moreover, it works fine if I install addon to already running instance of Firefox instead of launching `cfx run`.

Comment: can you manually check the main.js if the file content is exactly the same as the example in the guide?

Comment: @SebastianThoß No, I didn't make `cfx run` window work properly. Instead I used [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/) extension to speed up my development process.